# How to coerce a value to a String in Pony?

Tags: ponylang

I am trying to learn Pony, and for obvious reasons, one of the first things I want to do is print values.

However, it does not seem to work for most things, like:

```
env.out.print(2 + 2)
```

Gives the error:

```
Could not infer literal type, no valid types found
```

I also tried:

```
let four: U32 = 2 + 2
env.out.print(four)
```

But this gives an uglier error saying I need something that is a subtype of `ByteSeq`. Fine, but how do I get one of those?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to convert the integer into a `String`.

In Pony there is an interface called `Stringable` which declares the function `string(fmt)`, and a lots of classes implements that interface. Integers do for instance.

So just call `.string()` to convert a value in something printable.